# Using conan to build Qt from source does not build Qt5Help, Cmake cannot find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Help"

Tags: qt, cmake, conan

I am trying to use the qt conan package qt/5.6.2@osechet/stable to add qt to an existing project. For this project I need the Qt help package.

I have:

```
[requires]
qt/5.6.2@osechet/stable

[options]
qt:tools=True
```

in my conanfile.

How do I get the package to build with the Qt5Help package?

I have been unable to find Qt documentation on how Qt5Help is built to modify the package recipe. It is not listed as a module in the repository despite being listed here: http://doc.qt.io/qbs/qt-modules.html on the modules list.

Comment: I think this is not a conan question, but a very specific question about this package. You might get better help submitting an issue to: https://github.com/osechet/conan-qt

Comment: Also, having a quick look to the package recipe, it doesn't seem that there is any option to control de creation of the Qt5Help library, so either it is not created (and the recipe requires some changes), or it is created but the consumption is failing. Have you checked the package folder, the actual files, and it is not there?

Comment: It is not in the package folder after building. I am aware that it is not in the package as an option. I am interested in adding it to the package recipe but I cannot find how to do this in the Qt documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Qt5Help package is contained by building the tools submodule. The reason this did not work originally is that the conan package for `5.6.2` does not have the `tools` submodule option defined. To solve this I build my own conan package for `5.6.2` from the `5.8.0` master branch of the `osechet/conan-qt` repo.